# Excel VBA Worksheets.codename gives an error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet(tab)name called "data", the sheetcodename is also "data"
When I use;

```
Cells(rij, "K") = Worksheets("data").Cells(1, "F")
```

It works fine but when I use;

```
Cells(rij, "I") = data.Cells(1, "F")
```

It gives an error.

Comment: You can find the appropriate sheet names and codenames in the project explorer. `Codename(SheetName)`. You can directly reference codenames, but you have to reference the worksheetnames like your first piece of code.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error 91 during execution:
Object variable or block variable With is not set

Comment: Then `data` is not an sheet codename that actually exists.

Comment: See this link: http://ccvd.eu/i/vba.jpg

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  Something else is going on outside of the code snippet you have shown.

Comment: The code works well in worksheets and in Thisworkbook. But not in a module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the problem and have the solution.
I had declared several variables.

```
'Public cainA As Worksheet
'Public data As Worksheet
'Public eindblad As Worksheet

Sub reken(rij, kol, kolnaam)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

And now made these as comments.
Now it works.

Thanks for all your support.

Answer (score 0):

If You declare and set "data" it will work:

```
Dim data As Worksheet

Set data = Sheets("data")

Cells(rij, "I") = data.Cells(1, "F")
```

Edit:

If You got 1 sheet You can easily go with:

```
Dim data As Worksheet

Set data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Cells(rij, "I") = data.Cells(1, "F")
```

Comment: This does not work if the users change the tab name

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim str As String

    'Get the value of the cell using Tab name
    str = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("A1").Value

    'Get the value of the cell using Code name
    str = data.Range("A10").Value

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do :

```
Dim MySheet As worksheet

Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Cells(rij, "K") = MySheet.Cells(1, "F")

Cells(rij, "I") = MySheet.Cells(rij, "K")
```

Comment: I will use the codename because the user can change the tab name.

Comment: @Con I edited my code so you don't use sheets name, Does it work ?

Comment: If OP is worried about user changing tab name, they will be even more concerned about user moving sheet on different position :-)

Comment: @buran then there ls no viable solution as far as i know ;)

Comment: that is why they want to use CodeName instead - the most difficult for user to change it, although not impossible :-) The question is why it don't work as it should